# How to make TSConfig work in TYPO3 tx_news

Tags: typo3, typoscript, tsconfig

In TYPO3 6.1, how do I get the tsconfig for the tx_news news extension to work?

I try to add selectable layouts to news items:

```
tx_news.templateLayouts {
        1 = A custom layout
        99 = LLL:fileadmin/somelocallang/locallang.xml:someTranslation
}
```

This should add the new Layout to the Type field, as in:

[image: typo3 news backend]

or did I get that wrong? Where can that new custom layout be selected?

Also, I'm trying to prefill fields in flexforms (when a new plugin is inserted):

TCEFORM.tt_content.pi_flexform.tx_news.sDEF.categoryConjunction = and

But it does not work yet.

How can this be done?

Comment: Both configurations work in a 6.1 installation of mine with news 2.1.0. The 'tx_news.module' configuration is not for flexforms, but for the news module.

Comment: Thanks @Shufla! I got it wrong about the module. This works. I'll edit the question, there's more...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `tx_news.templateLayouts` you override the flexform for the news plugin you insert on a page, not for a news record.

Your second code looks almost right, but you forgot `settings`: `TCEFORM.tt_content.pi_flexform.tx_news.sDEF.settings.categoryConjunction = and`

And even though this code is right, it will not work because of a [bug](http://forge.typo3.org/issues/29461) with flexform fields that have a dot in their name (this is just stupid).
I think the only way to cleanly modify the flexform, is to write a small extension which overrides the default news flexform.

Comment: Ah, great, thanks! The patch has been under review for a while. Do you think it was forgotten?

Comment: Well, many critical bugs in TYPO3 or Extbase are kind of forgotten since months / years :)

Comment: There has been more activity recently. Just update the patch/bug to move it up in the review queue. Btw, the patch needs a manual rebase now.